# CSS - How to hide an element based on position within page?

Tags: css, element, hidden, sticky

I have a sticky element I've setup for a button on mobile devices. This is the code:

```
.sticky-btn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Works great but I don't want the button to show when the user is at the very top of the page. It would be perfect if it only appeared after you scrolled down say 20-30 pixels. Is it possible to accomplish this in CSS somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brian Preston. Unfortunately, we can't do this using only CSS. We should Javascript to add "sticky" class to sticky button and toggle button using that class.

```
.sticky-btn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.sticky-btn.sticky {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

And JS code should be like this.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    var stickyBtn = document.querySelector('.sticky-btn');
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

        scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    
        if (scrollPosition >= 30) {
            stickyBtn.classList.add('sticky');
        } else {
            stickyBtn.classList.remove('sticky');
        }
    });

});
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding ~ :)

Comment: Thanks for code snippet. This doesn't seem to be working for me though. This button only appears on mobile so I don't know if that impacts your code at all. This is the development site: https://3step.flywheelsites.com/   When I add the script and CSS the button doesn't show at all now.

Comment: @BrianPreston I've checked and realized that you've added script in head tag. That's why script doesn't work. I've updated JS code. Please replace with new one. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working on my end.

Comment: You're working on WP site, right? could you please share WP credentials with me? I'd like to check it on live.

Comment: What's your email? I'll make you a temporary login to check out the code. Yes, the site is on WordPress using the Avada theme as the basis for the site.

Comment: Added. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: @BrianPreston Updated answer and fixed on staging. Enjoy it :)